# Matrix representation of a transformation between vectors and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Given $T\colon\mathbb R^{n}\to\mathbb R_{2}\left[x\right]$ such that $T\left(1,0\right)=1+x,\ \ T\left(1,1\right)=1-x$ I need to find $T^{-1}\left(2x\right)$.

The solutions uses some sort of manipulation on $T^{-1}$ using the definition of $T$

$T^{-1}\left(2x\right)=T^{-1}\left(1+x-1+x\right)=T^{-1}\left(\left(1+x\right)-\left(1-x\right)\right)=T^{-1}\left(1+x\right)-T^{-1}\left(1-x\right)=\left(1,0\right)-\left(1,1\right)=\left(0,-1\right)$

But this seems tricky to me since it's something you have to notice by trial and error..

I've tried to brute force it using the matrix representation of $T$ with basis $\left(\left(1,0\right),\left(1,1\right)\right)$ for $\mathbb R^{n}$ and $\left(1,x\right)$ for $\mathbb R_{2}\left[x\right]$ but I got completely lost and got the wrong solution each and everytime..

What I tried to do (and I'm pretty sure I did alot of illegal stuff) was

$\left[T\right]_{B}^{C}=\left[\left[T\left(1,0\right)\right]_{C}\ \ \left[T\left(1,1\right)\right]_{C}\right]=\left[\left[1+x\right]_{C}\ \left[1-x\right]_{C}\right]=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}$

Then I found the inverse in $\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&-1}$ and got confused as to what to do with the $2x$, do I represent it according to basis $(1,x)$ as $(0,2)$ and then get

$\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&-1}\pmatrix{0\\2}=\pmatrix{1\\-2}$

Do I first turn in to $(0,2)$ and then represent it according to basis $((1,0),(1,1))$ and then get

$\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&-1}\pmatrix{-2\\2}=\pmatrix{0\\-1}$

The later seem to produce the correct result but I don't understand the procedure and I can't find anything in the class notes.. If someone could post how the procedure is actualy done I'd be really grateful

Comment: Are you told that $T$ is linear?

Comment: Yes, T is a linear transformation

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}_2 $?

Answer (score 1):

You can see that $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2 $. You can then work out what $T(0,1) $ is as $T(0,1)=T((1,1)-T(1,0))=1-x-(1+x)=-2x $ using that $T$ is linear.
So you are just finding a linear combination of $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ that makes $(0,1)$. By doing this we can see that $T(a,b)=aT(1,0)+bT(0,1)=a(1+x)+b(-2x)=a+(a-2b)x .$
So now for $T(a,b)=2x $ we need $a=0 $ and $b=-1$ so $T(0,-1)=2x$.
From this we see that $T^{-1}(2x)=(0,-1).$
Also $T^{-1}$ is also linear which justifies the steps in the solution you first gave.